# X and Y has the same distribution, prove E(X/Y)>= 1

Tags: probability, expectation

Let X and Y be two positive random variables with identical distribution (
not necessarily independent), prove $E(X/Y) \ge 1$.

Comment: Jensen's inequality
$E(e^{ln(Y/X)})>=e^{E(ln(Y/X))}=1$, is this correct?

Comment: Yes, assuming those expected values exist.  Without that assumption, consider truncated versions of $X$ and $Y$.